# How can I retrieve all conversations from Instagram using the API?

Tags: facebook

I have followed the official documentation to set up my Instagram Messaging API, including creating an app in my developer account, linking the business Instagram page with the page I'm an admin of, and creating a short-lived user access token with the required permissions (instagram_basic, instagram_manage_messages, pages_manage_metadata). However, when I make a request to the API, it only returns an empty array, despite being able to retrieve all conversations on Messenger without any issues. I'm looking for any advice or expertise on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.